# EclipseLink, lazy fetch collection is accessible outside of transaction

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have an entity named `User` which has the following field called `roles`:

```java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)}
)
private List<Role> roles;
```

I load the `User` via the use of a service method and the service method is wrapped in a transaction (JTA). After calling the service method and retrieving the `User`, I access this `role` field outside of the transaction that was used to load the `User` entity. I was expecting to get an error because the eclipselink documentation states that, by default, the fechtype for a ManyToMany association is [lazy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/ManyToMany). This tells me that when the `User` entity was loaded in the service method, the `roles` should not be automatically loaded.

Why was I able to access the `roles` outside of the transaction? Why does it seem like the `roles` were fetched eagerly instead of lazy?

Here is the service class which loads the user (I've removed some code not relevant to the question):

```java
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ServiceException.class)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public User authenticate(String username, String password) throws ServiceException {
        //Get the user
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (users == null || users.isEmpty() || users.size() > 1) {
            return null;
        }

        User user = users.get(0);
        String hash = getHash(password, user.getSalt());

        return StringUtils.equals(hash, user.getPassword()) ? user : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the code where the User is loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EclipseLink allows fetching lazy relationships as long as the context is still available as described here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1706796

Link is dead and I can't find the original post, but [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/cache001.htm) has a one line on it under "Container Managed Persistence Contexts":

> EclipseLink supports accessing an entity's LAZY relationships after the persistence context has been closed.

There have been a number of posts in this and other forms on the topic as it is a major differentiator from other JPA providers, as is its shared cache implementation which the feature is closely tied to.

Comment: Wow. That is exactly what I'm experiencing. This is my first time using Eclipselink, having used Hibernate in the past. In Hibernate I would have gotten an error.

Comment: Link's dead... :(

Comment: Too bad. I don't remember the details other than it was the best description of the feature and I believe it was from the PM at the time.