# When can a JPA lazy-loaded ManyToOne relationship be loaded outside of a transaction?

Tags: jpa, jax-rs, eclipselink, lazy-loading, jpa-2.1

I have a JAX-RS resource class.  It invokes a stateless EJB which loads an entity (let's call it `Parent`).

`Parent` has a `@ManyToOne` relationship with another entity (let's call it `Child`) and is configured as having a fetch type of `LAZY`.

No additional transactional annotations appear on anything, so the stateless EJB has the default behavior of starting a transaction when necessary, and committing the transaction once its business method has completed.

In a debugger, I observe that `Parent` as returned by the EJB has `null` as the value of `Child`, just as I'd suspect.  Lazy loading therefore is working fine.

My resource class then builds a `Response` and hands off control to the JAX-RS innards.  Again, no transaction is open.

After serialization, the JSON (in my case) that shows up contains all the fields of `Child`.  Something in the JAX-RS innards is somehow "inflating" that `Child` reference outside of the transaction.

I observe in a debugger that indeed at some point well after JAX-RS has taken over control that the `Child` reference has become non-`null`.

I thought that either `Child` should have stayed `null` or that an exception of some kind should have been thrown to indicate that someone tried to access a lazy-loaded field.  Clearly I misunderstood something.

Under what circumstances may a detached JPA entity have its lazily-loaded relationships "inflated" outside of a transaction?

If it matters, I'm using Jersey 2.10.4 by way of Glassfish 4.1 and EclipseLink 2.5.2 (again, by way of Glassfish 4.1).

Comment: Perhaps I'm seeing EclipseLink-specific behavior?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368075/eclipselink-lazy-fetch-collection-is-accessible-outside-of-transaction?rq=1) seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its truly "detached" then there is no context, hence no loading. If it is still in context then clearly it can load fields. This is according to the JPA spec.

Unless of course you're using some vendor-specific option, then you aren't following the JPA spec so can't rely on it in any other JPA implementation ...

Comment: My understanding is that a transaction-scoped persistence context (as usually found in a garden-variety stateless session bean-based app) has its lifespan defined by the transaction.  If that's true, then there is no context after the (transactional) EJB method completes for the entity to be "in" and hence the entity is "truly detached". Nevertheless I see lazy loading happening.  I'm JPA-conformant (no EclipseLink descriptors, options, etc.). Does that alter your answer? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whether the context is transaction or extended simply determines WHEN objects are detached, and if an object is DETACHED then it is not connected to the context ... what DETACHED means. That doesn't change anything in my answer. More than likely you are using some EclipseLink "different interpretation"/"extension" feature as referred to in http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/155   but as I already said, you cannot rely on that and be vendor independent

Comment: Thanks, Neil. Yes, to rephrase (equivalently), after my EJB method returns, any entity returned by it must be, by definition, detached. Totally in agreement. What I hear you saying, then, is: if the object is detached, which it is, then any loading it might do of lazy relationships is in violation of the JPA specification. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how *most* JPA implementations would interpret it. As that link says though, if EclipseLink has a 'detached' object, whilst the EM may be closed or not contactable, this object (somehow) retains a link to the EMF, so can still pull in fields (hence isn't really "detached" in the same sense as all other implementations interpret it).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, what's always bothered me about this vendor "feature" is the non-transactional nature of the object being loaded up. Maybe I'm missing something, but if at the time of the original transaction the lazy-loaded object on disk had state X, and then after the transaction a lazy load is triggered, and the object on disk changed state to Y...that seems potentially bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to start a transaction if you are only reading entities. For example the following code does not require transaction:

```
ParentEntity pe = entityManager.find(ParentEntity.class,1);
List<ChildEntity> childs = pe.getChildList();
System.out.println(childs.size());
```

However, please keep in mind that, as long as you are outside of transaction you will be unable to persist any changes to those entities.